# EOF file sentinal 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: vb.net, hex

In vb.NET
This should not be difficult.  I need to write an EOF marker of 0xFF FF FF FF to a file.  This is a simulated TAPE file on disk.

If I instatiate a BinaryWriter() called "bw"

Then at the end of my data writing seession I write:
bw.Write(255) ==> will output "FF 00 00 00" in the file in Little Endian format

However the HEX sentinal I require of FF FF FF FF is equivalent to 4,294,967,295 (Int64) and just for grinds I exrcute:
bw.Write(4,294,967,295) 
Yields FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 
Closer but not correct and I had to use a Int64 number.
Theoretically I could generate four instantiations of "FF 00 00 00" (255) and concatentate the FF's but that doesn't seem legit.

Comment: It is a vb.net quirk, the type of that literal is Integer, not Byte.  So you'll call the wrong Write() overload, writing 4 bytes instead of 1.  Use CByte(255).  Or a single Write(-1).

Comment: Solved! bw.Write(&HFFFFFFFFUI) will output "FF FF FF FF"

Comment: Cheers Hans! Just saw your post - I like that solution -- less kluggy than mine. You may mark as solved for the points.